# Toggle when clicking child element and not parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is when you click on the actual anchor tag...I want the div below to slide...The only way it slides toggle is if I change the click function target to be the ".flip" class and not on the ".flip a"

```js
// and Here is the JS
// Slide panels

$('.flip a').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next('div.panel').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
  <h4>Example</h4>
  <a href="">Link Button</a>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div>
<!--End panel-->

<div class="flip">
  <h4>Example</h4>
  <a href="">Link Button</a>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div>
<!--End panel-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` looks for siblings, which `.panel` isn't. You need to move up to the parent `.flip` element first.

```
$(this).closest('.flip').next('div.panel').slideToggle();
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

(You'll probably want to cancel the default click with `e.preventDefault()` as well.)

```js
$('.flip a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default click
  $(this).closest('.flip').next('div.panel').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
  <h4>Example</h4>
  <a href="">Link Button</a>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div>
<!--End panel-->

<div class="flip">
  <h4>Example</h4>
  <a href="">Link Button</a>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div>
<!--End panel-->
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer, next tries to find a same level element with the selectors provided, so you could use `.parent().next()`. Also, your href is taking you somewhere else when clicking on .flip a.

```js
$('.flip a').click(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().next('.panel').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
  <h4>Example</h4>
  <a href="#">Link Button</a>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div>
<!--End panel-->

<div class="flip">
  <h4>Example</h4>
  <a href="#">Link Button</a>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div>
<!--End panel-->
```